# Normalizing word frequencies

Tags: normalization, histogram

I have a data set that consist of a list of words with their frequency in a text. I want to normalize these frequencies into a range [0,1.0)

The 2 extreme approaches that come to mind are:

1. Distribute all words equally (i.e. sort by frequency and assign 'index/count'). This is too flat though, I want words with a very high frequency to also have a relatively higher score
2. Divide frequency by the total of all frequencies. This doesn't work well either, because a few words have a very high frequency, which yields a very uneven distribution (e.g. a few between 0.1 and 1.0, and everything else around 0.0001)

I'd like to have something in the middle, I.e. A flattened version of 2.

What's the standard transformation to smoothen out a distribution like this?

**Update**: I'm hoping for something general to smoothen out the distribution instead of something domain-specific (e.g. language aware such as text mining; the 'information' factor of words is not important, I *do* want to include the common words and stop words and give them a high score, just not as high so they silence out everything else.

Comment: Quick thought, the log basically linearizes exponential type stuff, though that doesn't give you a score betwen 0 and 1. Recalling a class I took eons ago, words are often assumed to follow the [Zipf distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law). A basic fact of natural language processing is that a few words (eg. "the" or "is") appear all over the place while the vast majority of words will appear just a few times. A huge amount of probability mass is in very long tails, and that's just the way it is.

Comment: You might add the [text mining](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-mining) tag. I do not have much experience, but I think a common approach is to use "term frequency–inverse document frequency" ([TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)). This however uses a collection (corpus) of texts, to try and automatically down-weight uninformative common words (e.g. [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words)).

Comment: @geomatt22 I was hoping for something general to smoothen out the distribution instead of something domain-specific. Also, for my application, the 'information' factor is not important, I do want to include the common words and give them a high score, just reduce it.

Comment: The [Variants of TF weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Term_frequency_2) part of the link I posted suggests the log approach from the first comment is commonly used perhaps.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 @MatthewGunn Thanks for the helpful pointers. `log` seemed obvious, but I couldn't get it to do what I want before; I suspect I was using it on the normalized frequencies instead of the actual frequencies. Using 1+log(freq) does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @GeoMatt22 and @MatthewGunn in the comments, `log` was what I was looking for (more specifically, `log(freq) + 1`).

Comment: Log doesn't do it, because its values can be arbitrarily negative.  If it really did solve your problem, then your problem was not what you have stated in the question!